# Cypress-wait-until - wait for element attribute to change

Tags: javascript, wait, cypress

I am testing an app that has a button that causes a value in another element on screen to change, without reloading the page. However, that change in value can be almost instant, or take several seconds. Obviously, I don't want to use some arbitrary wait, and I don't want to use a (hard) assertion - that might cause the test to stop with a fail that isn't a fail.... so I've been looking at cypress-wait-until (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until). I've written assorted variations along the lines of:

```
    waitForElemToChange(elem) {
        elem.invoke('attr', val').then((initialVal) => {
        cy.waitUntil(() => elem.invoke('attr', 'value').then((val) => val != initialVal))
    }
```

But nothing has worked so far - most attempts have resulted in "Timed out retrying: cy.invoke() errored because your subject is: null. You cannot invoke any functions such as attr on a null value."

Yet it's the same subject that just returned a value in the previous line??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This looks over complicated. I would approach it by waiting for `initialValue`, then waiting for a different value.

```
cy.get('input').should('have.value', 'myInitialValue');     // wait for initial value
cy.get('input').should('not.have.value', 'myInitialValue'); // wait for it to change
```

`.should()` will retry the assertion up to 4 seconds.

If by 'several seconds' you mean more than 4, you can add a timeout option, which is better than an arbitrary wait because it will continue as soon as the assertion passes.

I'm assuming your element is an input since you are accessing `val` not `text`.

Comment: Great answer, working for me with text:

`cy.get('element').should('contain', 'some text');`

Answer (score 8):

I went through your function and I think there are several issues with the usage. This might be a cypress related issue or the wait until plugin.

Firstly,
In your code, I think with **elem** you try to pass something like **cy.get("path")**
The problem is when you first invoke **elem** and try to re-use **elem**, it becomes null. So if you expect **cy.get('path')** to run twice, it's not happening.

Secondly,
For some reason, in your wait untill,

```
cy.waitUntil(() => elem.invoke('attr', 'value').then((val) => val != initialVal))

//This part becomes true all the time.
elem.invoke('attr', 'value').then((val) => val != initialVal))
```

Thirdly,

```
invoke('attr', 'value')
```

will not capture the changing attributes of the object.
Please note these observations are gathered from trying out what you tried to do. Need to extra research to find out the exact behaviour of the functions.

Considering the above facts, I did a few changes in the code.

- The main update of the changes are passing the CSS path instead of a cypress object (**elem**)
- using js query selector operations to get the changing value ( to take the initial value we can use invoke )

Example 1: Getting the new value inside waitUntil and check for a variable change

```
const CheckElementChange = (path) => {
    //get the initial value of your object
    cy.get(path).invoke('attr', 'value').then($initialVal => {
        //It's better if you can do your click operation here

        //Wait untill the element changes
        cy.waitUntil(() =>
        cy.get(path).then($newVal => 
            $newVal[0].value !== $initialVal),
            //optional timeouts and error messages
            {
                errorMsg: "was expeting some other Value but got : " + $initialVal,
                timeout: 10000, 
                interval: 500 
              }
        ).then(() => {
            cy.log("Foudn a difference in values")
        })
})
}
```

Example 2: move waitUntill after the new value extraction and wait till **newVal !== initialVal** to be true

```
const CheckElementChangew = (path) => {
    //get the initial value of your object
    cy.get(path).invoke('attr', 'value').then($initialVal => {
        //It's better if you can do your click operation here

        //Wait untill the element changes
        cy.get(path).then($newVal => {
            cy.waitUntil(() => $newVal[0].value !== $initialVal, {
                //optional timeouts and error messages
                errorMsg: "was expeting some other Value but got : " + $initialVal,
                timeout: 10000, 
                interval: 500 
              }).then(() => {
                cy.log("Foudn a difference in values")
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Usage :

```
it('test',() => {
    CheckElementChange2("#fname");
})
```

Note: If you expect the value change upon your click, unless the value change has a time gap of a few seconds, It's better if you can do the click after the extraction of the initial value ( as commented on the codes above )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin for this, you just need:

`cy.wrap({}).then(() => Promise((resolve) => { ... });`

Inside the promise, do whatever check you want; property changed, document loaded, whatever.

All that the various plugins that do this do is wrap it in a utility function like this:

```
const waitForProperty = (checkForProperty) => cy.wrap({}).then(() => new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
  // run this every 500ms until our condition is met or 60 seconds has passed. 
  let elapsed = 0;
  const checkIfResolvedYet = () => {
    elapsed += 500;
    if (checkForProperty()) {
      resolve();
      return;
    }

    // If it didn't resolve, check again in 500ms
    if (elapsed < 60000) {
      setTimeout(checkIfResolvedYet, 500);
    }
  };

  // Run initial check
  checkIfResolvedYet();
}));
```

So you can use it like this:

```
it("wait for property", () => {
  cy.visit("/");
  cy.get("#app").then(($app) => {

    // Some deferred thing here triggers a property change to wait for
    setTimeout(() => {
      $app.attr("data-test", "test-123");
    }, 1000);

    // Wait for the property to be set
    waitForProperty(() => {
      const value = $app.attr("data-test");
      cy.log("during query: " + value);
      if (value === "test-123") {
        return true;
      }
    });

    cy.log("the property is now set");
  });
});
```

> log during query: undefined
>
> log during query: undefined
>
> log during query: test-123
>
> log the property is now set

Yes, the plugins can save you writing about 10 lines of code.

...but if *you* write the code, you can add `cy.log` statements to debug exactly why your condition is not triggering.

If you need to use a plugin, use a plugin; but using `waitUntil` can lead to mysterious 'never works' situations which are impossible to debug any non-trivial cases.

In general, if a plugin can be replicated in < 10 lines of code, you may get more value from copying the equivalent code into your tests folder than from using the plugin.

Comment: Ubounded recursion, not good practice.

Comment: `.should('have.value', 'test-123')` does the same thing, that's the main feature of Cypress!